# Long equation or broken down equations what is faster in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, equation

Say I have the following code:

```
qwe = 1.5    

def jkl(l):
    result = 2*(math.pi/l)
    return result

def asd(b, l):
    result = (abs(((jkl(l)**2)*(qwe**2))-(b**2))**(0.5)
    return result
```

Now is it more efficient to have that long equation in the asd def or would it be calculated quicker if it was broken down:

```
def asd(b, l):
    z1=jkl(l)**2
    z2=qwe**2
    z3=b**2
    z4=(z1*z2)-z3
    z5=abs(z4)
    z6=z5**(0.5)
    return z6
```

As my code is potentially going to be used and modified by third-parties the broken down example is easy to follow, however does creating all those in-function variables slow it down more than doing it all in one line? It needs to be as fast as possible as that function will be called hundred of times by other functions that are even more complex.

Comment: Test python performance of code snippets using the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Comment: If there's any difference it'd be minor and based on whether the interpreter could find optimisations in one large statement that it couldn't in separated statements... If you've got a load of these "complex" calculations, have you considered using `numpy` ?

Comment: ...and use the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to get a better idea of what's going on in your code.

Comment: @JonClements: Any performance difference will lie in the assignment of local variables.

Comment: Feel free to post the results of timing both versions as an anwer :) On a side note: these aren't _equations_. Rather, expressions that are evaluated inside a function.

Comment: asd was just used for this to simplify it. I've used timeit, there is a difference although I'm not too sure how significant the difference is. 1 line ask gives 1.1537498028118132 whereas the broken down ask gives 1.2557689225396658. After replacing math.pi with a constant i get 1.1223440587650901. So thank you very much this should hopefully increase my code speed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell without measuring. Luckily, Python comes with the [module `timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) which does exactly that.

Just run both functions through `timeit.timeit()` and it will tell you which one is faster.

My gut feeling is that the compact one-line form is faster but I could be wrong.

And you may want to replace `2*math.pi` with a constant `PI2`:

```
PI2 = 2*math.pi
def jkl(l): return PI2 / l
```

and since function calls are expensive, you should inline this code into `asd()`

PS: I hope that the function names in the real code are more readable. :-) When I see `asd()` in the code of someone, I feel a strong rush of anger. :-)

Comment: `asd` could be "Average Standard Deviation"? :)

Comment: asd was just used for this to simplify it. I've used timeit, there is a difference although I'm not too sure how significant the difference is. 1 line ask gives 1.1537498028118132 whereas the broken down ask gives 1.2557689225396658. After replacing math.pi with a constant i get 1.1223440587650901. So thank you very much this should hopefully increase my code speed :)

Answer (score 1):

As many have suggested use python's `timeit` module to test the speed:

```
print timeit.timeit('asd(2,2)','from __main__ import asd')
print timeit.timeit('asd_split(2,2)','from __main__ import asd_split')

>>>0.93675494194
>>>1.0719628334
```

As expected the *non-split* version seems to be faster.

Comment: thanks, although I just ran my definition file (definitions.py) and then in the shell I put
`t = timeit.Timer('defintions.asd(8,0.6)','import defintions')` and then `t.timeit()`
which seemed to work just as well without the underscores :)